# Illegal character in array argument

Tags: tables, alignment, rotating

I produced a table several weeks ago (reference image attached) that I am now trying to add into a larger document. The first issue I am running into is that I now get an error message "Illegal character in array argument." I don't recall getting this error previously, and I am having trouble pinpointing the exact issue. To be honest, I think I found the table setup online, and since it worked at the time, I didn't question it.

Some things to note: The preamble in the tex file I am trying to add the table to is different from the test version I was using. I wasn't calling the dcolumn package, so I am not sure why I didn't run into this issue earlier. When I did try to play around with the dcolumn package, I ran into an issue where the final row is way out of alignment since it doesn't have any decimal places.

I've attached two photos: one of how the table looked when I compiled it several weeks ago, and the other is how it looks in Overleaf now (which is closer than how it looks when I use the dcolumn package but is still not centered on the page).

Here is what I have to produce the table:

```
\documentclass[11pt, english, letterpaper, fleqn]{article}%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{changepage} 
\usepackage{morefloats} 
\usepackage{afterpage} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.in, left=.75in, right=.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgffor} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\usepackage{rotating}


\newenvironment{fignote}{\begin{quote}\footnotesize}{\end{quote}}
\captionsetup{belowskip=0pt}

\pagenumbering{gobble}


\newcommand{\noi}{\noindent} 

\newif\ifw 



\title{abcd}}
\author{
    yyy
    \and
    zzz
    }

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{sidewaystable}[!htbp]
\caption{Disaster Severity} 
\begin{tabular}{l*{9}{D{.}{.}{-1}}}
\hline\hline
                &                                                                           && & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Years After Disaster}                                                  \\
                &\multicolumn{1}{c}{0}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{1}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{2}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{3}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{4}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{5}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{6}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{7}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{8}         \\
\hline
Disaster        &   -0.151         &    0.125         &    0.086         &    0.022         &    0.032         &   -0.025         &    0.305         &    0.419\sym{*}  &    0.399\sym{*}  \\
                &  (-1.60)         &   (1.12)         &   (0.62)         &   (0.14)         &   (0.18)         &  (-0.12)         &   (1.51)         &   (1.91)         &   (1.73)         \\
[1em]
Disaster $\times$ Damages&    0.000\sym{**} &    0.000\sym{**} &    0.000\sym{*}  &    0.001\sym{*}  &    0.001\sym{*}  &    0.001\sym{*}  &    0.001\sym{*}  &    0.001\sym{*}  &    0.001\sym{*}  \\
                &   (2.49)         &   (2.54)         &   (1.83)         &   (1.84)         &   (1.74)         &   (1.78)         &   (1.81)         &   (1.79)         &   (1.89)         \\
[1em]
Disaster $\times$ Damages$^2$&   -0.000         &   -0.000         &    0.000         &   -0.000         &   -0.000         &   -0.000         &   -0.000         &   -0.000         &   -0.000         \\
                &  (-1.03)         &  (-0.54)         &   (0.08)         &  (-0.86)         &  (-0.93)         &  (-0.92)         &  (-1.15)         &  (-1.25)         &  (-1.36)         \\
[1em]
Disaster $\times$ Damages$^3$&    0.000         &   -0.000         &   -0.000         &    0.000         &    0.000         &    0.000         &    0.000         &    0.000         &    0.000         \\
                &   (0.57)         &  (-0.40)         &  (-0.98)         &   (0.22)         &   (0.49)         &   (0.51)         &   (0.86)         &   (0.84)         &   (0.96)         \\
\hline
\rule{0pt}{1ex} &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
\emph{Net Effects}&                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
25th Percentile &   -0.151         &    0.126         &    0.087         &    0.024         &    0.033         &   -0.023         &    0.306         &   0.421*         &   0.401*         \\
                &  (-1.60)         &  ( 1.13)         &  ( 0.63)         &  ( 0.15)         &  ( 0.18)         &  (-0.12)         &  ( 1.52)         &  ( 1.92)         &  ( 1.73)         \\
50th Percentile &   -0.147         &    0.133         &    0.094         &    0.033         &    0.042         &   -0.014         &    0.315         &  0.430**         &   0.410*         \\
                &  (-1.57)         &  ( 1.20)         &  ( 0.69)         &  ( 0.21)         &  ( 0.23)         &  (-0.07)         &  ( 1.57)         &  ( 1.97)         &  ( 1.78)         \\
75th Percentile &   -0.132         &    0.164         &    0.130         &    0.077         &    0.083         &    0.028         &   0.358*         &  0.473**         &  0.454**         \\
                &  (-1.41)         &  ( 1.49)         &  ( 0.96)         &  ( 0.50)         &  ( 0.46)         &  ( 0.14)         &  ( 1.80)         &  ( 2.19)         &  ( 1.99)         \\
90th Percentile &   -0.064         &  0.302**         &   0.286*         &    0.271         &    0.263         &    0.216         &  0.545**         & 0.664***         & 0.645***         \\
                &  (-0.66)         &  ( 2.48)         &  ( 1.81)         &  ( 1.45)         &  ( 1.26)         &  ( 0.98)         &  ( 2.48)         &  ( 2.81)         &  ( 2.64)         \\
95th Percentile &    0.099         & 0.640***         &  0.668**         &   0.741*         &   0.698*         &   0.668*         &  0.992**         & 1.120***         & 1.102***         \\
                &  ( 0.77)         &  ( 2.97)         &  ( 2.11)         &  ( 1.90)         &  ( 1.77)         &  ( 1.67)         &  ( 2.52)         &  ( 2.74)         &  ( 2.77)         \\
97th Percentile &    0.237         & 0.928***         &  0.997**         &   1.140*         &   1.066*         &   1.050*         &  1.368**         &  1.502**         & 1.483***         \\
                &  ( 1.41)         &  ( 2.91)         &  ( 2.09)         &  ( 1.93)         &  ( 1.83)         &  ( 1.78)         &  ( 2.37)         &  ( 2.52)         &  ( 2.60)         \\
98th Percentile &   0.449*         & 1.383***         &  1.524**         &   1.763*         &   1.637*         &   1.644*         &  1.946**         &  2.087**         &  2.065**         \\
                &  ( 1.90)         &  ( 2.82)         &  ( 2.06)         &  ( 1.95)         &  ( 1.85)         &  ( 1.84)         &  ( 2.24)         &  ( 2.33)         &  ( 2.43)         \\
99th Percentile &  0.923**         & 2.448***         &  2.781**         &  3.191**         &   2.929*         &   2.989*         &  3.231**         &  3.377**         &  3.336**         \\
                &  ( 2.40)         &  ( 2.69)         &  ( 2.06)         &  ( 1.98)         &  ( 1.90)         &  ( 1.92)         &  ( 2.14)         &  ( 2.17)         &  ( 2.28)         \\
\hline          &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  &                  \\
R-squared       &     0.28         &     0.33         &     0.34         &     0.36         &     0.40         &     0.44         &     0.47         &     0.51         &     0.52         \\
Observations    &   97,879         &   97,800         &   94,804         &   91,809         &   88,819         &   85,828         &   82,839         &   79,855         &   76,871         \\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{10}{l}{\footnotesize \textit{t} statistics in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{10}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.1\), \sym{**} \(p<0.05\), \sym{***} \(p<0.01\)}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}


\end{document}
```

[image: This is how it looks in Overleaf now, but I am still getting the error when I try to recompile and can't do so on my desktop compiler]

[image: This is what I want it to look like]

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You do need to load `dcolumn` package to use column type `D`. The definition of `\sym` is also not provided in your example. Cells in the last row _is_ still vertically centered on `.`. It's just for this time the `.` is omitted. Attempt: for example for the cell in last row, second column, use `\multicolumn{1}{r}{97,879}` instead of `97,879`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1):

The two main changes you should make -- other than, of course, making sure to load all required packages, and especially the `dcolumn` package, and that all macros, incl. `\sym`, are defined -- are (a) replace `D{.}{.}{-1}` with something less spatially profligate, say, `D{.}{.}{2.6}` and (b) center the cell contents in the final two rows (Rsquared and No. of obs., respectively). Oh, and do please replace all instances of `\hline` with suitable alternatives provided by the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs/) package, such as `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, english, letterpaper, fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{changepage} 
\usepackage{morefloats} 
\usepackage{afterpage} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip}
\usepackage[vmargin=1.0in, hmargin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgffor} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}  
\usepackage{rotating}

\newenvironment{fignote}{%
  \begin{quote}\footnotesize}{%
  \end{quote}}
\captionsetup{belowskip=0pt}

%%\pagenumbering{gobble}

% new code:
\providecommand\sym[1]{^{#1}} % ??
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}  %[!htbp] % '[!htbp]' has no effect on 'sideways[table/figure]'

\caption{Disaster severity} 

\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{9}{D..{2.6}} @{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{9}{c@{}}{Years after disaster}\\
\cmidrule(l){2-10}
&\mc{0} &\mc{1} &\mc{2} &\mc{3} &\mc{4} &\mc{5} &\mc{6} &\mc{7} &\mc{8} \\
\midrule
Disaster & -0.151 & 0.125 & 0.086 & 0.022 & 0.032 & -0.025 & 0.305 & 0.419\sym{*}  & 0.399\sym{*}  \\
 & (-1.60) & (1.12) & (0.62) & (0.14) & (0.18) & (-0.12) & (1.51) & (1.91) & (1.73) \\ \addlinespace
Disaster $\times$ Damages & 0.000\sym{**} & 0.000\sym{**} & 0.000\sym{*}  & 0.001\sym{*}  & 0.001\sym{*}  & 0.001\sym{*}  & 0.001\sym{*}  & 0.001\sym{*}  & 0.001\sym{*}  \\
 & (2.49) & (2.54) & (1.83) & (1.84) & (1.74) & (1.78) & (1.81) & (1.79) & (1.89) \\ \addlinespace
Disaster $\times$ Damages$^2$ & -0.000 & -0.000 & 0.000 & -0.000 & -0.000 & -0.000 & -0.000 & -0.000 & -0.000 \\
 & (-1.03) & (-0.54) & (0.08) & (-0.86) & (-0.93) & (-0.92) & (-1.15) & (-1.25) & (-1.36) \\ \addlinespace
Disaster $\times$ Damages$^3$ & 0.000 & -0.000 & -0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 & 0.000 \\
 & (0.57) & (-0.40) & (-0.98) & (0.22) & (0.49) & (0.51) & (0.86) & (0.84) & (0.96) \\
\midrule
\emph{Net Effects} \\[0.5ex]
25th percentile & -0.151 & 0.126 & 0.087 & 0.024 & 0.033 & -0.023 & 0.306 & 0.421\sym{*} & 0.401\sym{*} \\
 & (-1.60) & (1.13) & (0.63) & (0.15) & (0.18) & (-0.12) & (1.52) & (1.92) & (1.73) \\
50th percentile & -0.147 & 0.133 & 0.094 & 0.033 & 0.042 & -0.014 & 0.315 & 0.430\sym{**} & 0.410\sym{*} \\
 & (-1.57) & (1.20) & (0.69) & (0.21) & (0.23) & (-0.07) & (1.57) & (1.97) & (1.78) \\
75th percentile & -0.132 & 0.164 & 0.130 & 0.077 & 0.083 & 0.028 & 0.358\sym{*} & 0.473\sym{**} & 0.454\sym{**}\\
 & (-1.41) & (1.49) & (0.96) & (0.50) & (0.46) & (0.14) & (1.80) & (2.19) & (1.99) \\
90th percentile & -0.064 & 0.302\sym{**} & 0.286\sym{*} & 0.271 & 0.263 & 0.216 & 0.545\sym{**} & 0.664\sym{***} & 0.645\sym{***} \\
 & (-0.66) & (2.48) & (1.81) & (1.45) & (1.26) & (0.98) & (2.48) & (2.81) & (2.64) \\
95th percentile & 0.099 & 0.640\sym{***} & 0.668\sym{**} & 0.741\sym{*} & 0.698\sym{*} & 0.668\sym{*} & 0.992\sym{**} & 1.120\sym{***} & 1.102\sym{***} \\
 & (0.77) & (2.97) & (2.11) & (1.90) & (1.77) & (1.67) & (2.52) & (2.74) & (2.77) \\
97th percentile & 0.237 & 0.928\sym{***} & 0.997\sym{**} & 1.140\sym{*} & 1.066\sym{*} & 1.050\sym{*} & 1.368\sym{**} & 1.502\sym{**} & 1.483\sym{***} \\
 & (1.41) & (2.91) & (2.09) & (1.93) & (1.83) & (1.78) & (2.37) & (2.52) & (2.60) \\
98th percentile & 0.449\sym{*} & 1.383\sym{***} & 1.524\sym{**} & 1.763\sym{*} & 1.637\sym{*} & 1.644\sym{*} & 1.946\sym{**} & 2.087\sym{**} & 2.065\sym{**} \\
 & (1.90) & (2.82) & (2.06) & (1.95) & (1.85) & (1.84) & (2.24) & (2.33) & (2.43) \\
99th percentile & 0.923\sym{**} & 2.448\sym{***} & 2.781\sym{**} & 3.191\sym{**} & 2.929\sym{*} & 2.989\sym{*} & 3.231\sym{**} & 3.377\sym{**} & 3.336\sym{**} \\
 & (2.40) & (2.69) & (2.06) & (1.98) & (1.90) & (1.92) & (2.14) & (2.17) & (2.28) \\
\midrule        
R-squared & \mc{0.28} & \mc{0.33} & \mc{0.34} & \mc{0.36} & \mc{0.40} & \mc{0.44} & \mc{0.47} & \mc{0.51} & \mc{0.52} \\
No.\ of obs. & \mc{97,879} & \mc{97,800} & \mc{94,804} & \mc{91,809} & \mc{88,819} & \mc{85,828} & \mc{82,839} & \mc{79,855} & \mc{76,871} \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{10}{@{}l}{\footnotesize $t$-statistics in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{10}{@{}l}{\footnotesize $\sym{*}\ p<0.1$; $\sym{**}\ p<0.05$; $\sym{***}\ p<0.01$.}
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```